# Trying to apply CSS3 animation to text in spans

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to apply a CSS3 animation to text wrapped in spans.

It works when the element has the class animated and the class of the animation name.

I'm using jQuery to add those classes as this animation happens on click and will be inside a click() function.
I also remove the classes before I add them because the classes can only exist once for the animation to work.

I've done this many times before, but for some reason it is not working when I try it on text wrapped in spans.

The jQuery seems to be working as in the developer tools I see the classes being added and remove on click, but the animation is not taking place.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.I').click(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('animated').removeClass('wiggle').addClass('animated').addClass('wiggle');
    });
});
```

And here is the CSS for the animation:

```
.animated{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}.animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;-moz-animation-duration:2s;-ms-animation-duration:2s;-o-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s;}@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
0% { -webkit-transform: skewX(9deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform: skewX(-8deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: skewX(7deg); }
30% { -webkit-transform: skewX(-6deg); }
40% { -webkit-transform: skewX(5deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: skewX(-4deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: skewX(3deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: skewX(-2deg); }
80% { -webkit-transform: skewX(1deg); }
90% { -webkit-transform: skewX(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: skewX(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
    0% { -moz-transform: skewX(9deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: skewX(-8deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: skewX(7deg); }
    30% { -moz-transform: skewX(-6deg); }
    40% { -moz-transform: skewX(5deg); }
    50% { -moz-transform: skewX(-4deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: skewX(3deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: skewX(-2deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: skewX(1deg); }
    90% { -moz-transform: skewX(0deg); }
100% { -moz-transform: skewX(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes wiggle {
    0% { -o-transform: skewX(9deg); }
    10% { -o-transform: skewX(-8deg); }
    20% { -o-transform: skewX(7deg); }
    30% { -o-transform: skewX(-6deg); }
    40% { -o-transform: skewX(5deg); }
    50% { -o-transform: skewX(-4deg); }
    60% { -o-transform: skewX(3deg); }
    70% { -o-transform: skewX(-2deg); }
    80% { -o-transform: skewX(1deg); }
    90% { -o-transform: skewX(0deg); }
100% { -o-transform: skewX(0deg); }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
    0% { transform: skewX(9deg); }
    10% { transform: skewX(-8deg); }
    20% { transform: skewX(7deg); }
    30% { transform: skewX(-6deg); }
    40% { transform: skewX(5deg); }
    50% { transform: skewX(-4deg); }
    60% { transform: skewX(3deg); }
    70% { transform: skewX(-2deg); }
    80% { transform: skewX(1deg); }
    90% { transform: skewX(0deg); 
100% { transform: skewX(0deg); }
}

.wiggle {
    -webkit-animation-name: wiggle;
    -moz-animation-name: wiggle;
    -o-animation-name: wiggle;
    animation-name: wiggle;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

**Update: Here is a fiddle that recreates the issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld8e/1/

Answer (score 1):

spans are inline or flow elements and therefore don't have position, height, width; they just flow according to their location.

Try changing the spans to have

```
display: inline-block
```

That should allow each span to have its own sizing attributes which can then be animated.

You also need to [let the browser redraw the page](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/08/17/when-does-javascript-trigger-reflows-and-rendering/) between when you remove the css classes and add them back. This doesn't happen when the classes are added and removed currently: the elements look the same to the browser before and after.

The best solution is to listen for the `animationend` event and then remove the classes (after the animation has executed).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var letters = $('.I');

    letters.on('animationend oanimationend webkitAnimationEnd', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('animated wiggle');
    });

    letters.on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated wiggle');
    });
});
```

Updated JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/3Ld8e/3/

Comment: I thought this might be the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. Here is a fiddle with the issue recreated: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld8e/1/

Comment: The browser wasn't redrawing between the addition of the classes and their removal ... so after the code executed, it looked the same to the browser. I've added code to show how to reset the classes when the animation finishes. Also simplified use of jQuery `addClass` function which can accept multiple classes (space delimited) http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class selector at the beginning of the Animation's CSS. Right now it is apply animation to element bazinga of class animated.